# Referral not received in google anlytics account

Tags: android, google-analytics, referrer

I am trying to receive referral parameters in google analytics account. But, it seems referrals are not received and the source and medium is direct\none.

```
try{
Bundle extras=null;
String referralString=extras.getString("referrer");
tracker.setReferrer(referralString);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

For the above code dummy parameters in the referral link are

```
source=sourcexyz
medium=referral
name=product.
```

Are, the above parameters okie?
What am i missing?
If the referrerString was wrong then i would get exception, but I am not getting any exception.

What are the preconditions to receive referral parameters in google anlytics account or Receieve data in referring sites, for android mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to register the receiver, `AnalyticsReceiver`.

You can see how to do that, and the different campaign parameters [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#android-market-tracking) - but `setReferrer()` may be enough depending upon what you are looking for.

Comment: but, why i can't see those campaign parameters in my account. Why i receive the installations as direct/none.My query not yet solved.

Comment: did you do what I said, regarding the Receiver? Looked at the parameters at the site I linked?

Comment: doesn't appear to be, the example is: (original referrer, e.g. google, citysearch, newsletter4)

Comment: Now, I tell you wht parameters i have included, source as myCompanyName, medium is referral and campaign name is product.                     The market link is roughly as  http://market.android.com/details=details?id="My Application Pacakge Name"&referrer=utm_source%3D"My company Name"%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dproduct               In my onReceive, i have set referrer using the code i mentioned above with GoogleAnalytics object.

Comment: I want installation data i.e the referral data to be send when installation is done. i.e Only Once.

Comment: save it as a preference, if the preference is already there, don't send it again.

Comment: why do i use preference, as i want to send the data once after the application is downloaded and installed

Comment: @CrackerJack9 have any idea i have posted my question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431018/how-to-get-referrer-using-google-track-in-android