# how to get referrer using google track in android?

Tags: android, tracking

I want to implement install referrer track and want referrer parameter and store in back end database i have seen many exmple or question as on like [Get Android Google Analytics referrer tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817030/get-android-google-analytics-referrer-tag) or [Android Google Analytics Campaign tracking not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233875/android-google-analytics-campaign-tracking-not-appearing) but not get a way i have generated links to and try the code

```
   package SimpleDemo.ReferralTrack; 

   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
   import java.net.URLDecoder;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Map;

   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.SharedPreferences;
   import android.os.Bundle;

  public class ReferralReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
   {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    // Workaround for Android security issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16006
    try
    {
        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            extras.containsKey(null);
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        return;
    }

    Map<String, String> referralParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Return if this is not the right intent.
    if (! intent.getAction().equals("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")) { //$NON-NLS-1$
        return;
    }

    String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    if( referrer == null || referrer.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    try
    {    // Remove any url encoding
        referrer = URLDecoder.decode(referrer, "x-www-form-urlencoded"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { return; }

    // Parse the query string, extracting the relevant data
    String[] params = referrer.split("&"); // $NON-NLS-1$
    for (String param : params)
    {
        String[] pair = param.split("="); // $NON-NLS-1$
        referralParams.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }

    ReferralReceiver.storeReferralParams(context, referralParams);
}

private final static String[] EXPECTED_PARAMETERS = {
    "utm_source",
    "utm_medium",
    "utm_term",
    "utm_content",
    "utm_campaign"
};
private final static String PREFS_FILE_NAME = "ReferralParamsFile";

/*
 * Stores the referral parameters in the app's sharedPreferences.
 * Rewrite this function and retrieveReferralParams() if a
 * different storage mechanism is preferred.
 */
public static void storeReferralParams(Context context, Map<String, String> params)
{
    SharedPreferences storage = context.getSharedPreferences(ReferralReceiver.PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storage.edit();

    for(String key : ReferralReceiver.EXPECTED_PARAMETERS)
    {
        String value = params.get(key);
        if(value != null)
        {
            editor.putString(key, value);
        }
    }

    editor.commit();
}

/*
 * Returns a map with the Market Referral parameters pulled from the sharedPreferences.
 */
public static Map<String, String> retrieveReferralParams(Context context)
{
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SharedPreferences storage = context.getSharedPreferences(ReferralReceiver.PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    for(String key : ReferralReceiver.EXPECTED_PARAMETERS)
    {
        String value = storage.getString(key, null);
        if(value != null)
        {
            params.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    return params;
}
}
```

After that i have try in my activity

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(DemoActivity.this);
              String  referrers1 =preferences.getString("ga_campaign", "0");
              Map<String, String> retrieveReferralParams=ReferralReceiver.retrieveReferralParams(DemoActivity.this);
              String  referrers2= retrieveReferralParams.get("utm_source");
              String  referrers3= retrieveReferralParams.get("utm_medium");
              String  referrers4= retrieveReferralParams.get("utm_term");
              String  referrers5= retrieveReferralParams.get("utm_content");
              String  referrers6= retrieveReferralParams.get("utm_campaign");
              tv.setText(referrers1+" "+referrers2+" "+referrers3+" "+referrers4+" "+referrers5+" "+referrers6+" ");
```

on button click but not get desired output

i want something like from

```
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lifestreet.android.TestInstallationIntent&referrer=bb%3DAAAAAAAAAA&feature=search_result%22"  
 Ans     

   referrer=bb
```

any help me highly appreciated 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u get it working? If yes, is it still working for you?

Comment: It returns null for me in all fields

Comment: Is it still running for you?

Comment: @Khan  ... Did u get the solution of yours problem...i have also stucked in these problem...plz help me to short out from these problem

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that Google lets you send arbitrary information. Try using the generator to create the url.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-builder

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue. Found it to be lifecycle problem: the onReceive of the install_referrer receivers are invoked AFTER my app's onResume(), on the SAME main thread, so any attempt to read the referrer file during onResume() fails. Here is the logcat to prove it, this was 100% reproducible over and over on 2 devices using Android 4.2.1 and 4.4.2:

First, play store broadcasts the referrer to the package on a separate (store) process:

```
11-04 14:17:51.558: D/Finsky(1737): [1] ReferrerRebroadcaster.doBroadcastInstallReferrer: Delivered referrer for com.xxx.demo
```

The app onResume() - still no activation of the broadcast receivers! S

```
11-04 14:17:51.888: D/XXX Main Activity(22730): onResume
```

The app tries to read the referrer (which the receivers should have stored using getSharedPreferences.putString):

```
11-04 14:17:51.958: I/XXX(22730): Extracted install referrer:
```

Only now the receivers are invoked on the main thread and will shortly try to write the referrer to a file:

```
11-04 14:17:51.918: I/XXX(22730): Received install referrer: abcdefg
```

As you can see, onResume() has no chance to actually read the file, so the extraction yields nothing. However, if I close the app and reopen it, onResume is now able to find the file and the referrer string gets processed - but not on first launch :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics uses arbitrary constants in their SDK.
for campaing_source is &cs.