# get referrer using google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracking, referrer

I have an app located in some servers (not in Google Play) and I want to know from which one it has been downladed, I read about it and it looks like I have to do it by using a BroadcastRecever and a filter: INSTALL_REFERRER as in this post [how to get referrer using google track in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431018/how-to-get-referrer-using-google-track-in-android)

I didn´t find any example working so if you could help would be great

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [from which web my app was downloaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014402/from-which-web-my-app-was-downloaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was to export the same app with different names and upload them in different webs, now I can take the apk name and then the page were the app was downloaded

Thanks everybody